# Best way to combined AND and OR in Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents containing a `tags` array and a `city` field. I try to query something like this in ES:

**(javascript OR html OR css) AND Los Angeles**

Best way to do that?
URI solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Elasticsearch query to get `(javascript OR html OR css) AND Los Angeles`

```
{
    "filter": {
        "and": {
           "filters": [
              {
                    "term": {
                       "city": "Los Angeles"
                    }
              },
              {
                "or": {
                   "filters": [
                      {
                          "terms": {
                             "tags": ["javascript","html","css"]
                          }
                      }
                   ]
                }
              }
           ]
        }
    }
}
```